# How to Make a Twitter Bot Run From Dropbox?

Tags: twitter, cloud, dropbox

I have made a simple Twitter bot for favouriting tweets, retweeting, following specific people, and so on. But I have to start it when I want it to work. How can I "host" the bot on Dropbox? I want it to run "forever" from Dropbox servers, to keep my bot functional even when I'm not connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can not run a executable by Dropbox as it is only a file hosting service.

For running your program *somewhere else* you need a server or a web hosting account (maybe coupled with a cron-job).

This depends on your used programming language.

Comment: Thanks. I searched more about it and Heroku fit my job.